# WAF Rule to deny query parameter with script tags through Cloud Front

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf

I have a requirement to create a WAF rule to deny a query parameter with script tags when requests come through Amazon Cloud Front. I don't want to use AWS Common Rule Set instead want to write an custom rule. I have tried following PERL compatible regular expression but it didn't work. Can you suggest a pattern to define in WAF.

Regular Expression evaluated till now:`<script[^>]*>.\*?\</script>`

It works only with regular expression: `(.\*)script(.\*)`

But this is incorrect as it blocks requests if a query parameter contains "script"

Comment: How about `<script.*</script>`

Comment: No that didn't work.